# Union query and group by on Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, errors

I have two queries with a union, my problem is group articles for **Codice** then added **Quantità** and **Totale** of items with the same codes, the problem is shown in the image (see two rows for `GW44001`).

**SQL CODE:**

```
SELECT SottoCapitolo.Codice,SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,ISNULL(SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura,'NR') as UM,SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario,SottoCapitolo.Quantita,(SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario*SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Totale
  FROM Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
  inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
  on Capitolo.IdCapitolo=SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo

where SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Articolo' 

UNION ALL

/*Selezione Articoli Dentro Distinte*/
Select Articolo.CodArt as Codice,Articolo.Descrizione,ISNULL(Articolo.UM,'NR'),Articolo.Prezzo,SottoCapitolo.Quantita*(DistintaSemplice.Quantita) as Quantita,cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo*(SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita*SottoCapitolo.Quantita))),2) as numeric(12,2)) as Totale
from Fatture.dbo.Preventivo
inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
on Capitolo.IdPreventivo=Preventivo.IdPreventivo
inner join Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo=Capitolo.IdCapitolo
inner join Fatture.dbo.Distinta
on SottoCapitolo.Codice=Distinta.IdDistinta
inner join Fatture.dbo.DistintaSemplice
on DistintaSemplice.IdDistinta=Distinta.IdDistinta
inner join Fatture.dbo.Articolo
on Articolo.IdArticolo=DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo

where SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Distinta'

group by Articolo.CodArt,Articolo.Descrizione,Articolo.UM,Articolo.Prezzo,SottoCapitolo.Quantita,DistintaSemplice.Quantita
```

Output:

> [image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53297/discussion-on-question-by-riki-dev-union-query-and-group-by-on-sql-server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/*Selezione Articoli*/

```
SELECT 
SottoCapitolo.Codice,
SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,
SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario,
SottoCapitolo.Quantita,
(SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario*SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Totale
  FROM Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
  inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
  on Capitolo.IdCapitolo=SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo

where SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Articolo' 

UNION /* or ALL */

/*Selezione Articoli Dentro Distinte*/
Select 
Articolo.CodArt as Codice,
Articolo.Descrizione,
Articolo.Prezzo,
SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita*(DistintaSemplice.Quantita)) as Quantita,
cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo*    (SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita*SottoCapitolo.Quantita))),2) as numeric(12,2)) as Totale
from Fatture.dbo.Preventivo
inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
on Capitolo.IdPreventivo=Preventivo.IdPreventivo
inner join Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo=Capitolo.IdCapitolo
inner join Fatture.dbo.Distinta
on SottoCapitolo.Codice=Distinta.IdDistinta
inner join Fatture.dbo.DistintaSemplice
on DistintaSemplice.IdDistinta=Distinta.IdDistinta
inner join Fatture.dbo.Articolo
on Articolo.IdArticolo=DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo

where SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Distinta'

group by 
Articolo.CodArt,
Articolo.Descrizione,
Articolo.Prezzo
```

or Group by should be for the both:

```
SELECT
    Codice,
    Descrizione,
    CostoUnitario,
    SUM(Quantita) AS Quantita,
    SUM(Totale) AS Totale
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        SottoCapitolo.Codice,
        SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,
        SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario,
        SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita) AS Quantita,
        SUM(SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario*SottoCapitolo.Quantita) as Totale
    FROM 
        Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
        INNER JOIN Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
            ON Capitolo.IdCapitolo=SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo
    WHERE
        SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Articolo' 
    GROUP BY
        SottoCapitolo.Codice,
        SottoCapitolo.Descrizione,
        SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario

    UNION ALL

    /*Selezione Articoli Dentro Distinte*/
    SELECT 
        Articolo.CodArt as Codice,
        Articolo.Descrizione,
        Articolo.Prezzo,
        SUM(SottoCapitolo.Quantita*(DistintaSemplice.Quantita)) as Quantita,
        cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo*    (SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita*SottoCapitolo.Quantita))),2) as numeric(12,2)) as Totale
    FROM
        Fatture.dbo.Preventivo
        INNER JOIN Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
            ON Capitolo.IdPreventivo=Preventivo.IdPreventivo
        INNER JOIN Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
            ON SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo=Capitolo.IdCapitolo
        INNER JOIN Fatture.dbo.Distinta
            ON SottoCapitolo.Codice=Distinta.IdDistinta
        INNER JOIN Fatture.dbo.DistintaSemplice
            ON DistintaSemplice.IdDistinta=Distinta.IdDistinta
        INNER JOIN Fatture.dbo.Articolo
            ON Articolo.IdArticolo=DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo
    WHERE
        SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Distinta'
    GROUP BY
        Articolo.CodArt,
        Articolo.Descrizione,
        Articolo.Prezzo
)Q
GROUP BY
    Codice,
    Descrizione,
    CostoUnitario
```

Answer (score 0):

The question here is that some field of GW44001 is different in both sentence, well try to fix it:

This query shoul compare field by field, take care of the sintax, maybe I've made some mistake.

```
SELECT 
       case when SottoCapitolo.Codice = sq.Codice then 'Codice =' else 'Codice <>' end  as Codice,
       case when SottoCapitolo.Descrizione = sq.Descrizione then 'Descrizione =' else 'Descrizione <>' end  as Descrizione,
       case when SottoCapitolo.UnitaMisura = sq.UnitaMisura then 'UnitaMisura =' else 'UnitaMisura <>' end  as UnitaMisura,
       case when SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario = sq.CostoUnitario then 'CostoUnitario =' else 'CostoUnitario <>' end  as UnitaMisura,
       case when SottoCapitolo.Quantita = sq.Quantita then 'Quantita =' else 'Quantita <>' end  as Quantita,
       case when (SottoCapitolo.CostoUnitario*SottoCapitolo.Quantita) = sq.Totale then 'Totale =' else 'Totale <>' end  as Totale
FROM Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
     inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo on Capitolo.IdCapitolo=SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo
     inner join (
                    Select Articolo.CodArt as Codice,
                           Articolo.Descrizione,
                           CASE WHEN Articolo.UM = '' THEN 'NR' ELSE ISNULL(Articolo.UM,'NR') END as UM
                           Articolo.Prezzo,
                           SottoCapitolo.Quantita*(DistintaSemplice.Quantita) as Quantita,
                           cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo*(SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita*SottoCapitolo.Quantita))),2) as numeric(12,2)) as Totale
                    from Fatture.dbo.Preventivo
                         inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo on Capitolo.IdPreventivo=Preventivo.IdPreventivo
                         inner join Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo=Capitolo.IdCapitolo
                         inner join Fatture.dbo.Distinta on SottoCapitolo.Codice=Distinta.IdDistinta
                         inner join Fatture.dbo.DistintaSemplice on DistintaSemplice.IdDistinta=Distinta.IdDistinta
                         inner join Fatture.dbo.Articolo on Articolo.IdArticolo=DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo
                    where SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Distinta'
                         AND Articolo.CodArt = 'GW44001'
                ) sq on sq.Codice = SottoCapitolo.Codice
where SottoCapitolo.Tipo='Articolo'
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two **different** Quantita in the group by

```
Select Articolo.CodArt as Codice
     , Articolo.Descrizione
     , ISNULL(Articolo.UM,'NR')
     , Articolo.Prezzo
     , SottoCapitolo.Quantita*(DistintaSemplice.Quantita) as Quantita
     , cast(ROUND((Articolo.Prezzo*(SUM(DistintaSemplice.Quantita*SottoCapitolo.Quantita))),2) as numeric(12,2)) as Totale
from Fatture.dbo.Preventivo
inner join Fatture.dbo.Capitolo
on Capitolo.IdPreventivo=Preventivo.IdPreventivo
inner join Fatture.dbo.SottoCapitolo
on SottoCapitolo.IdCapitolo=Capitolo.IdCapitolo
inner join Fatture.dbo.Distinta
on SottoCapitolo.Codice=Distinta.IdDistinta
inner join Fatture.dbo.DistintaSemplice
on DistintaSemplice.IdDistinta=Distinta.IdDistinta
inner join Fatture.dbo.Articolo
on Articolo.IdArticolo=DistintaSemplice.IdArticolo   
where SottoCapitolo.Tipo = 'Distinta'  
group by Articolo.CodArt
       , Articolo.Descrizione
       , Articolo.UM
       , Articolo.Prezzo
       , SottoCapitolo.Quantita
       , DistintaSemplice.Quantita
```

This has nothing to do with the union
Learn to break down a problem and format a query so you can debug